# C# regular expression to get words between 4 to 10 characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get all the words in a string, that are at least 4 characters long and less than 10 characters. When I use the following regular expression, it just returned the whole string as one word. Can you please look at the following example and tell me how should I write this regular expression?

```
string result = "Overfishing, erosion and warmer waters are feeding jellyfish blooms in coastal regions worldwide. And they're causing damage"
string[] words = Regex.Split(result, @"[\W]{4,10}");

foreach (string line in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: `.Split.Where(s => s.Length > 3 && s.Length < 11);`.  Regex is overkill for such a trivial condition.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers and comments, they were all helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the pattern will only match a sequence of 4 to 10 consecutive non-word characters, which doesn't appear in the string. So `Regex.Split` just returns an array containing the original string.

Try using this pattern:

```
\b\w{4,10}\b
```

For example:

```
string[] words = Regex.Matches(result, @"\b\w{4,10}\b")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

This will match any sequence of 4 to 10 consecutive word characters, surrounded by word boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Without regex, you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string result = "Overfishing, erosion and warmer waters are feeding jellyfish blooms in coastal regions worldwide. And they're causing damage";
var array = result.Split(new string[] {",", ".", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in array)
{
   if(item.Length >= 4 && item.Length < 10)
      Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
erosion
warmer
waters
feeding
jellyfish
blooms
coastal
regions
worldwide
they're
causing
damage
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/PQPomE)</kbd>.